# Error handling in Three.js Loader.load()

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using a JSONLoader in Three.js and I don't know how to handle error when loading the model.

For example:

```
// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'models/animated/monster/monster.js',
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( geometry, materials ) {
        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        scene.add( object );
    }
);
```

If the resource isn't available, the load operation fails but the callback function is never called. 
As it seems that no error callback function can be provided and a "try catch" pattern will not work due to the asynchronous operation, how can I detect and perform an action when this load operation fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it would appear that you can specify an onError callback, it just doesn't seem to be well documented. Check the source code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js

Edit:

Yep.

https://jsfiddle.net/gwpzo5eq/

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("this load will fail", onSuccessCallback, onProgressCallback, onErrorCallback);

function onSuccessCallback(){}
function onProgressCallback(){}
function onErrorCallback(e){
    alert("JSONLoader failed! because of error " + e.target.status + ", " + e.target.statusText);
}
```

I'm not sure why the documentation appears to be incorrect. The correct `.load` function signature is:

```
JSONLoader.load( url, onLoad, onProgress, onError )
```

I've opened up an issue on the THREE.js github page.